# Does the IBM Cloud DNS solution offer any way to resolve names internally to IBM?

Tags: dns, ibm-cloud

My team is moving our environment to the IBM Cloud (formerly softlayer). Our DNS servers are currently managed by a 3rd party (AT&T) and via their infoblox devices. We have numerous A and other pointer records that point to IBM internal zones such as rochny.ibm.com and rny.smbdi.ibm.com.  I am wondering if those records would be resolvable by the Cloud DNS solution or vice versa?  Do the Cloud DNS solutions capable of forwarding to internal IBM DNS for name resolution in the private ibm.com namespace?

I am also interested in zone transfer from our current DNS environment to the cloud DNS solution(s), which would be contingent on the answer to my first question.  Is it possible to do zone transfers to the IBM Cloud DNS being offered?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as absolutely not related to programming. Also, did you start by asking your new prospective provider about all questions you have in using it? Its support should be far more authoritative than anyone here or on other more on topic forums?

Comment: Thanks.  I was directed to ask the question here via an IBM Cloud page link on their DNS Services FAQ.  I suspected it wasn't the right venue but figured it was worth a try.  Appreciate the response.